# dot notation , window object and its properties

Tags: javascript, scope, this, window-object

I am trying to learn some new concepts about javascript.Here is a simple code I wrote. Inside a function THIS keyword refers to global object which is window unless it's bind with the context of another object. Inside `myobj` object there are two methods which shares a same name with another two globally accessible function called `afunc` and `anotherfunc` respectively. I want to access those global function within myobj context and of course without using binding global object to a immediately invoked function which I used to call them. But it is throwing an error. **My question is if everything in javascript is an object and window object holds them ,then why can i access those function using `this.afucn` or `window.afunc`?**

```js
(function(){
var afunc=function (){
    document.write('this is world'+'</br>');
}
var anotherfunc=function (){
   document.write('this is another world');
}
   var myobj={
       afunc:function(){
         document.write('afunc');
    },
    anotherfunc:function(){
         document.write('anotherfunc');
    },
    context:function(){
        (function(){
         this.afunc();
      this.anotherfunc();
     })();
    }
  };
   myobj.context();
})();
```

Comment: as far as I know everything in JS is an object not function.

Comment: Everything in javascript is not a function, but almost everything is an object. Primitives are wrapped in a temporary object. You are wrapping `myobj` in an IIFE which makes it inaccessible on the `window` object.

Comment: Not everything in JavaScript is a function, and not everything in JavaScript is an object.

Comment: _Almost_ everything is an object.

Comment: typing mistake ..sorry :( edited the post

Comment: I don't see where you are defining the global variables you are talking about. It's true, `this` will refer to the global object, so it will work if you have such global variables.

Comment: @FelixKling the afunc and anotherfunc variables before myobj.Shouldn't i call them global variable??

Comment: The are not global, they are **local** to the function you have around the whole code. Move them outside and it will work.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is true that in your case, `this` will refer to the global object and `this.afunc()`, etc will access the global variable `afunc`.

However, unless there is more code to show, **you don't have a global variable `afunc`**. The variables you defined with

```
(function(){
var afunc=function (){
    document.write('this is world'+'</br>');
}
var anotherfunc=function (){
   document.write('this is another world');
}
//...
})();
```

are **local** to the enclosing function (the `(function(){ ... })();` part).

If you want to make them global, you can just move them outside the function:

```js
var afunc = function() {
    document.write('this is world' + '</br>');
};
var anotherfunc = function() {
    document.write('this is another world');
};
(function() {
    var myobj = {
        afunc: function() {
            document.write('afunc');
        },
        anotherfunc: function() {
            document.write('anotherfunc');
        },
        context: function() {
            (function() {
                this.afunc();
                this.anotherfunc();
            })();
        }
    };
    myobj.context();
})();
```

---

**However**, note that in *strict mode*, `this` would be `undefined`, not referring to the global object. This was done because usually if someone uses `this` inside a function, they don't expect it to refer to the global object. By just looking at the code, it's not always clear whether you want to access the global object (via `this`) or some other object (and as you noticed, there was some confusion about your intend).

That's why, if you want to access the global object, you should do so explicitly and refer to it via `window`.

Answer (score 1):

First things first, I think you have some things a little bit confused.

In JavaScript, *not* everything is a function.  Instead, there are a few different primitives one can use (as of ES5):

1. String
2. Number
3. Boolean,
4. Null
5. Undefined
6. Object

*Recommended Reading: [Mozilla Documentation on JavaScript Data Structures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures)*

Each of these types has special methods associated with it - except for `null` and `undefined`, those are placeholders with very specific usages - but those aren't important for helping to fix your understanding of what's going on in JavaScript.  One of the keys that *will* help, is the idea that JavaScript is what's called a **functional language**.  In part, this means that functions are first-class objects.  Among other things, this means that it is possible to use a function as a value.

Another thing, is that said returned functions aren't the *only* thing that gets returned - what happens is that function programming is built around the idea of a *closure*, or a function and all the relating variables in the scope that the returned function was defined (after all, we could be referencing variables in the function that's returning our new function!)

```
function foo() {
    var bar = 3;

    // Returns a function that when called, returns the Number 5.
    return function () {
        return 1 + 1 + bar;
    }
}
```

As far as narrowing down your error is concerned, in your `myObj.context` function, I notice you've written an immediately-invoking expression...

```
context: function () {
    (function () {
        this.afunc();
        this.anotherfunc();
    })();
},
```

Is that really necessary?  In fact, is that function really necessary at all?  Since we now know that JavaScript treats functions on an object as values, you can always just do `myObj.afunc` or `myObj.anotherfunc` to work with the code specific to `myObj`.

If your intent was to write a method that would call the `afunc` and `anotherfunc` methods on `myObj`, a better set of code would be:

```
var myObj = {
    afunc: function () {
        // Magic!
    },
    anotherfunc: function () {
        // More magic!
    },
    context: function () {
        this.afunc();
        this.anotherfunc();
    }
};
```

If your intent is to call the `afunc`/`anotherfunc` defined in the immediately-invoking expression surrounding the declaration of `myObj`, simply remove the `this` from the calls in `context`.

If your intent is to call the `afunc`/`anotherfunc` methods on the global scope, then you are plumb out of luck: you have not defined such functions in the given snippet.  However, this could be fixed like so:

```
// Now, afunc exists in the global scope!
function afunc() {
    // Magic
}

// Now, anotherfunc exists in the global scope!
function anotherfunc() {
    // Magic
}

(function () {
    var myObj = {
        // Your object...
    };

    myObj.context();
})();
```

Generally, though, this is considered bad programming form, because we're cluttering the global scope with unnecessary functions, variables, and objects; it's a better idea to keep your function declarations inside of the immediately-invoking object, unless you need to call them in other places.  If you need to call these functions in other places, you might consider researching the ways you would do that.

Comment: FYI, primitive values are not Objects.

Comment: Uhm, now it's even more confusing *"there are a few different primitives one can use"*. There are six types in JS. String, Number, Boolean, Null, Undefined are primitive types and then there is Object. Some primitive types (String, Number, Boolean) have Object equivalents. Functions and Arrays are just Objects.

Comment: This is better source than W3Schools: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures

Answer (score 0):

It's not working because `this` is not referring to what you think it's referring to, it's holding on to the `window`. In which from there, the functions are outside are not entirely in the global scope because they are wrapped within `(function(){ ... })();`. Now to your `context` function, we don't want the `function()` wrapper because nothing is in global scope:

```
   context:function(){
       (function(){ // <-- Here
           this.afunc();
           this.anotherfunc();
       })(); //        <--
   }
```

Remove that (we don't want it anyways) and `this` will refer to an instance of `myobj`

```
   context:function(){
       this.afunc();
       this.anotherfunc();
   }
```

If we want to get the ones declared outside of `myobj` scope, then you don't want to use `this`. Because that means the functions that belong to the instance of `myobj`. You just want to say:

```
   context:function(){
       afunc();
       anotherfunc();
   }
```

Because `myobj` does not know about the "global" functions.

```js
(function(){
var afunc=function (){
    document.write('this is world'+'</br>');
}
var anotherfunc=function (){
   document.write('this is another world');
}
   var myobj={
       afunc:function(){
         document.write('afunc');
    },
    anotherfunc:function(){
         document.write('anotherfunc');
    },
    context:function(){
               afunc();
               anotherfunc();
    }
  };
   myobj.context();
})();
```

Comment: @Johan `this` is scope dependent.

Comment: This doesn't seem to answer the OP's question.

Comment: i think u misunderstood me. i don't want to print myobj's methods.I want to print the afunc and anotehrfunc fuction which had been declared globally by making a call to myobj.

Comment: @Johan Fixed, sorry I noticed it didn't have a `$` at the start.

Comment: *"it's holding on to the (function(){"* what does that even mean? Are you claiming that `this` refers to the function itself? I can assure you that that's not the case.

Comment: @FelixKling Then what does `this` refer to?

Comment: To the global object, i.e. `window`.

Comment: @FelixKling No, sorry, but you are completely wrong about that. `this` refers to the global object if it's not in any scope or in any function. But when it's inside a "function" (object) it refers to that object. That's why `this` is used for `myobj` and not `window`.

Comment: I'm talking about the first code snippet in your answer... you as well?

Comment: @FelixKling Ah, yeah that's true in that case. Sorry, I thought you were saying it's always the global object. My misunderstanding.

Comment: For those who down-voted could you explain what I'm doing wrong?